# Big O analysis log^2 vs linear

Tags: runtime, big-o

For a reasonably large number of elements `n`, which one is generally considered better? `O(n)` or `O(log^2(n))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`O(log^k(n))` is a lower bound than `O(n)` no matter how high `k` gets. It's still "sublinear". That's not the same thing as "better", of course; asymptotic complexity is only one piece of the optimization puzzle.